# recursive function variable initialization

Tags: java, recursion

Edit: the initial values of sum and i should be 0.

I have received a task where I need to use recursion. Currently the code will not run because I have not initialized the variables "sum" and "i".

Does anyone have any ideas about how I could accomplish the task without adding in additional arguments to the evalHornerRec method?

```
// example data: a = {2, 1, -2, 6, 4, 3}, x = 3

public static double evalHornerRec(double[] a, double x)
{

    int len = a.length;
    int i;
    double sum;


    if (i >= len)
    {   
        return sum;
    }

    else
    {   
        sum += a[i] * Math.pow(x, i);
        i++;
        return evalHornerRec(a, x);
    }   

}
```

Comment: couldn't you just initialize sum and i where you call the function? You could make a wrapper-method where you set the sum and i and then call it.

Comment: are you allowed to use extra functions?

Comment: @LuaiGhunim short answer no, although it wouldn't be the end of the world if I do.

Comment: @Christian quite possibly, but I am such a beginner I don't even know what that would look like. I would need to do some googling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like each recursive call should operate on a smaller array. If you can't add `i` as an argument to the recursive call, you can pass a sub-array instead of the full array.

As for `sum`, I'm assuming that should be the value returned by the method, so I'm assuming you should add the result of the recursive call to the term added in the current call.

```
public static double evalHornerRec(double[] a, double x) {
    int len = a.length;   
    if (len <= 0) {   
        return 0.0;
    } else {   
        double[] subArray = Arrays.copyOf(a,len-1);
        return evalHornerRec(subArray, x) + a[len-1] * Math.pow(x, len-1);
    }   
}
```

EDIT: my answer was based on what you seemed to be doing in your question, but based on [this description of Horner's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method), perhaps the recursion you are supposed to calculate is actually:

```
evalHornerRec(a,x) = a[0] + x * evalHornerRec (sub array of a[1] to a[n-1])
```

Which would look like this:

```
public static double evalHornerRec(double[] a, double x) { 
    if (a.length == 1) {   
        return a[0];
    } else {   
        double[] subArray = new double[a.length - 1];
        System.arraycopy(a, 1, subArray, 0, subArray.length);
        return a[0] + x * evalHornerRec(subArray, x);
    }   
}
```

P.S., these two recursive methods are equivalent.
For the input you suggested (a = {2, 1, -2, 6, 4, 3}, x = 3), both give the same result - `1202.0`. However, the second method makes more sense for recursive implementation. The first one can be computed with a simple for loop without any recursion, so it defeats the purpose of using recursion.

Comment: Impressive and elegant solution!

I only have one small question about System.arraycopy (Sorry, I am quite a beginner). why do we need to specificy the subArray.length value? I have read a description [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) and i understand its simply part of the function, but isnt that information redundant, given you specified the subArray length in the previous line of code?

Many thanks once more!

Comment: @doom01 `System.arraycopy` requires the start index in the source and target arrays, as well as the number of elements you wish to copy. It doesn't necessarily fill the target array.